# Como carregar scripts js dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web que precisa carregar arquivos js dinamicamente. A razão para isso é que há uma lógica necessária para a seleção de quais scripts são requeridos, sendo que dessa forma scripts desnecessários não são carregados.

O problema é que não sei como fazer isso. Pensei no RequireJS, mas como estou trabalhando com angular acabei deixando isso pra la, porque a única forma que encontrei de se trabalhar com AMD usando angular não me pareceu muito natural.

Como posso carregar scripts dinamicamente? Basicamente, pensei em uma chamada ajax para uma url do serviço web que seria capaz de selecionar os scripts e devolver esses dados, mas não sei como usar isso pra realmente carregar os scripts.

Comment: Por que não executar diretamente um `eval` ou inserir um `<script>` com o código no DOM após o ajax retornar?

Comment: Apesar de no começo parecer uma boa ideia, carregamento seletivo de scripts acaba resultando em problemas futuros, como maior carga no servidor devido ao maior número de requisições necessárias, maior tempo de interpretação de scripts e maior tempo de latência. Recomendo fortemente abandonar este método ou avaliar se este é realmente o melhor caminho a se seguir.

Answer (score 11):

Não precisa de Ajax, simplesmente crie um elemento tipo `script` e injete no DOM:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = ""; // URL do seu script aqui
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Você pode controlar o que fazer após o carregamento com um handler para o evento `load`:

```
script.onload = function() {
    // daqui você pode carregar seus scripts dependentes
};
```

Se você quer construir um sistema simples de carregamento assíncrono de scripts, esses são os blocos básicos.