# Carregar uma tag scrip apos outra tag script ter carregado por completo

Tags: javascript, html

Quero carregar uma tag script somente quando a outra estiver COMPLETAMENTE carregada.

Exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptUm.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptDois.js"></script>
```

quero que o scriptDois carregue apenas depois o scriptUm tenha carregado COMPLETAMENTE.

Já tentei algumas maneiras porem todas estavam relacionadas ao carregamento da pagina, gostaria de uma maneira que esteja relacionada ao carregamento de outro script.

Comment: Da maneira como você colocou, elas já são carregadas em sequência.

Comment: Talvez essa pergunta te ajude https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138892/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-incluir-um-arquivo-javascript-dentro-de-outro-arquivo-javascript

Comment: @bfavaretto Me corrija se eu estiver errado, eles de fato são executados em sequencia, contudo não o scriptDois executa independente de o scriptUm ter terminado sua execução por completo.

Comment: O segundo executa quando terminar a execução do primeiro. A não ser que você esteja disparando operações assíncronas (timers, ajax) e queira carregar o segundo ao final dessas operações. Nesse caso o carregamento vai depender de como é o código do primeiro script. Talvez isto te ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14544

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usa o script1 como chave para iniciar o script2

```
function script1() {
    //codigos que quer que seja executado primeiro
    return script1(true);
}

function script2(keyRun) {
    if(keyRun){
        //o que quiser que execute
    }
}
```

Dessa forma o script2 só vai executar quando o script1 terrminar de ser executado.

Caso você esteja usando funções assíncronas no script1, você terá que tratá-lo com Promise, mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
async function script1() {
    myCode = (resolve, reject) => {
        //vou usar o fetch como exemplo de função assincrona
        fetch(url)
            .then((html) => {resolve(script2(true))})
            .catch((error) => reject(console.error(error)));
    }
    return await new Promise(myCode);
}

function script2(keyRun) {
    if(keyRun){
        //o que quiser que execute
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, se der algum erro o script2 não será executado, mas isso pode ser facilmente resolvido com o devido tratamento dos erros

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o atributo defer da tag script.

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptUm.js"></script>  
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptDois.js"></script>
```

Desse modo o carregamento do script passa do padrão (fetch seguido da execução), que pausa o carregamento do HTML, para o fetch assíncrono e execução em sequência após o carregamento do HTML de acordo com a ordem de chamada dos arquivos.